Why does ZMQ context close blocks forever?
I have the following code snippet. There the context.close() blocks forever. Does anyone have a hint on how to fix this? I suspect this is happening because I send a message but never receive an answer, as the close() doesn’t block if I do get a response. The question is, what if I don’t get a response? How can I close the context in this case without causing a deadlock? I use libzmq 4.3.4 and cppzmq 4.7.1.
#include <zmq.h>

int main()
{
 zmq::context_t context(1);
 zmq::socket_t socket1(context, zmq::socket_type::req);
 const std::string foo("foo_");
 socket1.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:8889");
 zmq::message_t msg(foo.size());
 std::memcpy(msg.data(), foo.c_str(), foo.size());
 socket1.send(std::move(msg), zmq::send_flags::none);
 socket1.set(zmq::sockopt::rcvtimeo, 500); //block for 50mms as expected
 socket1.recv(msg);
 socket1.disconnect("tcp://127.0.0.1:8889");
 socket1.set(zmq::sockopt::linger, 0);
 socket1.close();
 context.close(); //code blocks here, everything else works fine
}


Please only add language tags for the language you are using. Unless you want to know differences between C and C++ or you want to combine them, using both tags does not make sense.

For ultimate clarity where the as-is code blocks, best interleave every SLOC with a GUI printing "reporter" ( for example showing a copy of SLOC, time, zmq_errno ). This way you can demonstrate where code works as you expect and where not. Distributed systems debugging is a different discipline, than a monolythic localhost-only, non-cooperating, serial-code debugging. Reproducibility of errors is another new Universe in realms, where gangs of distributed applications work independently one of any other, weakly coordinated at maximum. This indeed a completely new ZOO, where cages are open


Q1 :" (...) what if I don’t get a response? "

Your .recv()-call will hang, as documented & instructed. In all ( indeed  underscored, ALL incl. in all schoolbook-naive examples ) signalling & messaging applications prefer to use :
( a ) a Poller.poll( ZMQ_NOBLOCK ) decorated pre-test, if any message has already got arrived into a respective localhost Context()-instance, before calling a "pre-ACK-ed" .recv( ZMQ_NOBLOCK )-method to finally indeed "read" data ( out from the localhost side Context()-engine queue storage ) into your application hands ( Zero-Copy feature has its value here in doing it ),
or
( b )an "event-loop"-alike, scheduled, blind noblock-/fast-/slow- reader-loops, where .recv( amount_of_waiting )-call does not hang forever and lets other parts of the application logic continue to run.
As documented in earlier versions native API of ZeroMQ, ZMQ_LINGER attribute was recommended to get set right after instantiation via .setsockopt()-method, so as to prevent any unwanted and intermitent hangups ( in early versions v2.0.11 I remember even cases the O/S wXP had to get rebooted, as hanging Context orphans from exception panicked code were stillllllll, teeth and nails,  (b)locking address/ports where not handled properly ... yes, the time is so, sooo fast ). Newer ZeroMQ versions added another option, to setup / profile the actual Context()-instance to instantiate further Socket()-instances with ZMQ_LINGER already set to pre-configured value, so best review your version of language binding, which version of ZermMQ native C-API calls are correctly mirrored and use either of the above ways to set ZMQ_LINGER early (  be it a-priori, ASAP or just "early enough" ) before the Socket()-instance starts to ever get "used". Nobody wants to "debug" distributed causes of dealocks / livelocks, as Pieter HINTJENS & Martin SUSTRIK so many times argued.

Q2 :" How can I close the context in this case without causing a deadlock? "

Best never get into such conflicting state. A few strategies above give your code, if used systematically, advantage of never loosing control of what is when executed ( almost a soft-realtime event-driven system can be scheduled in this very way - used it many times in "controlled" multiplexing "attention" among many, different priority, sockets with tight "turn-around-time" requirement to keep controls of many devices in a gang of remote devices, so one socket should work well enough, if similar care is taken for a solo-socket to never hangup a Context with an unhandled Socket()-instance, caught in a non-recoverable distributed Finite State Automaton ( dFSA, like the REQ/REP is known to be since ever - may enjoy other post to see more details on this deadlock, that is certain that it happens, uncertain only when it happens ).
Anyways, enjoy the Zen-of-Zero & good luck

ZMQ_REQ isnt a great pattern, its good for some example code but I would not use it in a production system as it deadlocks easily if you call recv but there is no reply. You could look at ROUTER/DEALER which are more flexible but more difficult to setup/understand.
The workaround for REQ/REP is to poll the socket for incoming events, using the poller as your timeout. Then only read if the the poller gets an incoming event.
Change this code
 socket1.set(zmq::sockopt::rcvtimeo, 500); //block for 50mms as expected
 socket1.recv(msg);

To this (or something similar - I have not tested it, may not compile).
 // Set up a poll items (could be more than one)
 zmq::pollitem_t items [] = {{socket1, 0, ZMQ_POLLIN, 0}};
 // Poll the socket for incoming messages, after 500ms timeout if no data
 zmq::poll (&items [0], 1, 500); 
 // If your poller indicates there are messages available read them 
 if(items[0].revents & ZMQ_POLLIN) {
  socket1.recv(msg);
 }

